# Translate Ui-grid Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm trying to translate Ui-grid in angular but i can't . i just want to translate `columnDefs` .
**here is my controller :**

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {

        enableSorting: true,
        columnDefs: [

                  { name: 'نمایش', cellClass: "editCell", cellTemplate: '<i id="editBtn" tooltip-placement="left" tooltip="نمایش درخواست" class="fa fa-eye" ng-click="getExternalScopes().editUser(row.entity.RequestCode)" ></i>', headerClass: 'JobHeader' },

                   {
                       name: 'کد شهر',  headerClass: 'cityHeader', field: 'CityCode', editableCellTemplate: self.editableCellTempate, 
                       enableCellEdit: true
                   },
                    { name: 'کد امور', field: 'RgnCode' },
        { name: 'شماره درخواست', field: 'RequestCode' },

        ],


    };
```

i want to translate `name in columnDefs`

Any idea ?

Comment: This will help you https://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/adding-translation-using-angular-translate-to-an-angularjs-app/.  also refer this https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fangular-translate.github.io%2Fdocs%2F&ei=xtcsVei8KM6RuASavoHABQ&usg=AFQjCNGVIm2E5QthYNFJKVu6m71htu05Lw&bvm=bv.90790515,d.c2E

Answer (score 7):

Use

- cellFilter:'translate' for cell,
- headerCellFilter:'translate' for header
- footerCellFilter: 'translate' for footer

in colummDefs

Comment: @sani, no, just add another option like `enableCellEdit: true, cellFilter:'translate' `

Comment: can't do it but i solved it with this: headerCellTemplate: '<div>{{"common.Display"|translate}}</div>'

Comment: You should just be able to add to your columnDef `headerCellFilter: 'translate'`.  Obviously you also need angular-translate installed for this path.  Overriding the headerCellTemplate as you have done also works, but is less tolerant of upgrades - if we change the headerCellTemplate in ui-grid you'll need to change your template when you upgrade.  Using headerCellFilter doesn't have that problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with 'useStaticFilesLoader' or isn't reliable. may it has something to do with the asynchronous load?

Answer (score 6):

I used `{field:'id', displayName:'ID_TRANSLATION_KEY', headerFilter:'translate'}`. It works like usual template translation. Only problem with your solution you may be losing default sorting functionality offered by the component (have to create your own) when you use **`headerCellTemplate`**. 
I think this may help someone.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually translate it, use name as the fieldname in your data, and then set displayName to whatever you want.

If you want to do on-the-fly translation using angular-translate, then as @YOU said.

Answer (score 0):

Use `displayName` and `$translate.instant('...')`:

```
{
   name: 'CityCode',
   displayName: $translate.instant('CityCode'),
   headerClass: 'cityHeader',
   editableCellTemplate: self.editableCellTempate, 
   enableCellEdit: true
}
```